# string which is sent to other compononent with router.push is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Well, I have two components. From one component I would like to send a string to another component where the string should be displayed on the console. This is the component where the data is pushed to the other component:

```
this.$router.push({path: "/editService", params:{data: 'test'}})
```

This is the second component. In here the string should be displayed:

```
    export default {
  data(){
    return{
      ServiceData: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.ServiceData=this.$route.params.data
    console.log(this.ServiceData)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Vue Router, then you should have a route defined similar to

```
{
   path: '/editService/:routeData',
   component: User,
   props: true
}
```

then add a prop to your user component:

```
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      ServiceData: this.routeData
    }
  },
  props: {
    routeData: {
      type: String, // at least for test
      required: true
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.ServiceData)
  }
}
```